# Knockout complex viewmodel problems

Tags: knockout.js

Could someone assist in explaining the probably fundamental fault I am doing.
I need to be able to have a model which can group a list of objects each with its own set of bindings.

A fiddle shows what I what to do with an example of only 1 block but in the end I want multiple blocks.

Html

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"
type="text/javascript"></script>
<div class="productblock">
  <div class="product">
    <input class="binding" data-bind="value: amount" type="text" value="1">
  </div>
  <div class="product">
    <input class="binding" data-bind="value: amount" type="text" value="2">
  </div>
  <input class="discount" data-bind="value: discount" value="50">
</div>

</div>
  <span id="res" data-bind="text: result">result here </span>
```

js

```
function ResultViewModel() {
  this.result = ko.computed(function () {
    return 1;
  });
}

function ProductViewModel(val) {
  this.amount = ko.observable(val+1);
  this.sum = function () {
    return this.amount();
  };
}

  var products = [];
function ProductBlockViewModel(block) {
  $.each($(block).find("div.product"), function (index, element) {
    var product = new ProductViewModel($(element).find("input").val());
    products.push(product);
    ko.applyBindings(product);
  });
  this.discount = ko.observable(22);

}
var productBlocks = [];
$.each($("div.productblock"), function (index, element) {
  console.log("a");
  var productBlock = new ProductBlockViewModel(element);
  productBlocks.push(productBlock);
  ko.applyBindings(productBlock, element);
  console.log("asdf");
});
```

ko.applyBindings(new ResultViewModel());
http://jsfiddle.net/Todilo/DGUKu/2/

Comment: If you check the browser console, you will see there's an error that stop your code to be executed. I still don't understand what you want to achieve. I believe there's another way to make the code more simpler and overlap applyBindings are not recommended

Comment: I need to be able to map
A productblock
 1 product
 2 product
B productblock
 1 product
 2 product
some other things

but I cant find any example of this that uses existing data

Comment: Basically its the nesting I cant figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DGUKu/7/

I will re-structure your code to make it cleaner.

HTML:

```
<!-- ko foreach: productBlocks -->
<div class="productblock">
   <!-- ko foreach: productLines -->
  <div class="product">
    <input class="binding" data-bind="value: amount" type="text">
  </div>
  <!-- /ko -->
  <input class="r" data-bind="value: discount" value="50">
</div>
    <hr/>
<!-- /ko -->

<div>
<span id="res" data-bind="text: result"></span>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function ProductModel (){
  this.amount = ko.observable(0);
  this.sum = function () {
    return this.amount();
  };
}

// product block contains multiple product line
function ProductBlockViewModel(productArray) {
  this.productLines = ko.observableArray(productArray);
  this.discount = ko.observable(50);
}

// your viewmodel for binding data
// should call applybindings only one
function ViewModel(){
  this.result = ko.observable(0);
  this.productBlocks = ko.observableArray([]);
}

var viewModel = new ViewModel();

// let assume you have 2 blocks:

// block 2 products
viewModel.productBlocks.push(new ProductBlockViewModel([
  new ProductModel(), new ProductModel()
]));

// block 3 products
viewModel.productBlocks.push(new ProductBlockViewModel([
  new ProductModel(), new ProductModel(), new ProductModel()
]));

// you can calculate your total result here
viewModel.result(100);

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Comment: That looks like a very good start but how do I approach it when I already have the html and the list of blocks defined? So I want to "read them" from the DOM.

Comment: you mean you have a string html as a template?

Comment: I mean like if I already have the productblocks defined on the page and I want to bind then after they have been created. Here you create them using the foreach and then the push into the observable array. The problem is that the productsblocks have a lot of other information and the page as a whole comes from an MVC asp.net. So I want to "read" that html structure and put it into models which can calculate the costs based on blocks, products etc

Comment: I know I am stretching what knockout is ment to do but I felt like jQuery was not really built for dynamically updating like I need and I havent found any other alternative

Comment: In this case, you should try JQuery Template. Try this link: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-tmpl and http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2010/11/30/an-introduction-to-jquery-templates.aspx

Comment: That would unfortunatley require me to extract all the razorviews. The thing is that the page wont get more products dynamically. What happens is only the user inputs amount, a cost is calculated based on amoun+cost-discount and that is displayed. With the html already defined it felt like it wouldnt be that hard to create a logic which grouped it into product, blocks etc and then update then based on changes to their inputfields.

Comment: In the end, knockout was not for me. Thank you for your help.